# Populate state/province dropdownlist according to country dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Right now I have a method that fills the country dropdownlist using system.globalization. What I would like to know is if there is any way I'd be able to load the states/province of the country when a given country is selected.

```
 Public Sub fillCountryDDL()
        Dim objcountries As New List(Of String)()
        Dim objculture As CultureInfo() = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
        objcountries.Add(String.Empty)
        For Each getculture As CultureInfo In objculture
            Dim objregion As New RegionInfo(getculture.LCID)
            If Not (objcountries.Contains(objregion.EnglishName)) Then
                objcountries.Add(objregion.EnglishName)
            End If
        Next
        objcountries.Sort()
        ddlCountry.DataSource = objcountries
        ddlCountry.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Is there something in system.globalization that handles this?

I've heard that one way to do this is by running a JS script. I'm currently attempting this, but have not been successful.

Comment: what does your JS script  look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately System.Globalization does not contain this information. You will have to find a different source for State/Province by country data.

This question talks about calling a webservice, or creating your own database to use.
[Getting States and Provinces in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123819/getting-states-and-provinces-in-net)